# Numerical Analysis help in MatLab

Tags: matlab, math

I am in a numerical analysis class, and I am working on a homework question. This comes Timothy Sauer's Numerical Analysis, and is in the second suggested activity section. I have been talking with my professor about this code, and it seems the error and the approximation are wrong, but neither one of us are able to figure out why. The following code is what I am using, and this is in MatLab. Anyone know enough about Euler Bernoulli beams, and Matlab who can help out?

```matlab
function ebbeamerror %This is for part three

   disp(['tabe of errors at x=L for each n'])
   disp(['             n ','        Aprox ','      Actual value','       Error'])
   disp(['======================================================='])
   format bank
    
   for k = 1:11
      n = 10*(2^k);
      D = sparse(1:n,1:n,6*ones(1,n),n,n);
      G = sparse(2:n,1:n-1,-4*ones(1,n-1),n,n);
      F = sparse(3:n,1:n-2,ones(1,n-2),n,n);
      S = G+D+F+G'+F';
      S(1,1) = 16;
      S(1,2) = -9;
      S(1,3) = 8/3;
      S(1,4) = -1/4;
      S(2,1) = -4;
      S(2,2) = 6;
      S(2,3) = -4;
      S(2,4) = 1;
      S(n-1,n-3)=16/17;
      S(n-1,n-2)=-60/17;
      S(n-1,n-1)=72/17;
      S(n-1,n)=-28/17;
      S(n,n-3)=-12/17;
      S(n,n-2)=96/17;
      S(n,n-1)=-156/17;
      S(n,n)=72/17;
         
      E = 1.3e10;
      w = 0.3;
      d = 0.03;
      I = w*d^3/12;
      g = -9.81;
      f = 480*d*g*w;
      h = 2/10;
      L = 2;
      x = (h^4)*f/(E*I);
      x1 = ones(n ,1);
      b = x*x1; 
      size (S);
      size(b);
      pause
      y = S\b;
      x=2;
      a = (f/(24*E*I))*(x^2)*(x^2-4*L*x+6*L^2);
      disp([n y(n) a abs(y(n)-a)])
   end 
end
```

Comment: Proper indentation is sooo important. I totally misread your code at first. Anyway, please [edit] your code with expected output and actual output, it might help pinpoint your issue.

Comment: Most of the text in your question tells us nothing at all about what you're actually trying to achieve. Please re-read it, imagining you're a complete stranger on the internet with no context, then [edit] it to include a [mcve] including the problem statement, and expected inputs/outputs.

Comment: I know a good bit about both beams and numerical analysis.  I'm guessing that you are trying to predict beam deflections and comparing a finite element numerical solution with a closed-form answer.  A few words about geometry, loading, boundary conditions, and units would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Bernoulli's beams but i know a lot about numerical analysis. This may not be your problem but its very good to read what I'm about to write no matter how long you have been programming.

When dividing by an integer the carry bit of a computer can result in wrong answers and produce rounding errors. I see you are using for instance /17 everywhere and 24, 12, 3 and 4 in other places. You must always make these values floats so that they appear in code as 17.0, 24.0, 12.0, 3.0 and 4.0. If everything is an integer in a formula, the result can be cast as an integer.

Also, if the numbers are small and you are trying to create tolerances and convergence figures in numerical computations, the rounding error can become very significant leading to wrong answers. So ideally, use floats or doubles for absolutely everything, including multiplication.

Note in particular that E is massive in your formulation and therefore 1/E is tiny. This suggests to me that rounding error is a highly likely reason for your approximation and errors.

Comment: I don't dispute most of what you write but, you do know that by default all Matlab numbers are doubles, don't you?  To define an integer variable you have to write something like `myInt = int64(10)`.  `myInt = 10` leaves `myInt` as a double.

Comment: That's why you must explicitly must set x=10.0 to make it a float instead of using x=10.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the fact that it is using symbolic manipulation could also be an issue: https://matlab.fandom.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_0.3_-_0.2_-_0.1_.28or_similar.29_not_equal_to_zero.3F